# Developing Application for Windows 7 : Best practices/things to watch out for

Tags: .net, windows-7

As someone who will someday be developing applications for use in Windows 7 in .NET, I was wondering what are the best things to do while programming for Windows 7 and also, the things we should be aware of when doing it.

Comment: What version of Windows do you currently target?  If it's XP the list of things to look out for is much different than if its Vista.

Comment: Good question. polished the english

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that your application can run as a "standard" user. (Don't do stuff that require elevated privileges)

Answer (score 1):

Biggest thing I've noticed when writing apps that use the [Windows 7 API codepack](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/WindowsAPICodePack) is that anybody trying to use your app in Vista or XP will hate you if you don't gracefully handle them.  Its nice to have and use the 7 bling, but not everybody's playing with the cool kids yet.

Comment: And you get to decide if you want to spend the extra time to be inclusive, or quickly impress a smaller user base. Both approaches are workable.

Answer (score 1):

Two things I can think of:

1. Test/run you application on both 32 *and* 64 bit systems
2. Make sure to test/run your application with UAC on